# API call from https node application never reaches the destination

Tags: node.js, express

I have a node.js application served over https. I would like to call an API from that application. The API is also served over https and it has been generated using the express-generator.
Unfortunately the call never works. There is no error message. The call never reaches the API.
Strangely enough if I try to call another public API (e.g. [https://api.publicapis.org/entries'](https://api.publicapis.org/entries%27)) that is working perfectly.

Here is my call:

```
const requestBody = {
  'querystring': searchQuery,
};

const options = {
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  keepAlive: false, // switch to true if you're making a lot of calls from this client
};

return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  const sslConfiguredAgent = new https.Agent(options);

  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
    agent: sslConfiguredAgent,
    redirect: 'follow',
  };

  fetch('https://192.168.112.34:3003/search', requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(result => resolve(result))
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
      });
};
```

And here is the API which I would like to call:

```
router.post('/', cors(), async function(req, res, next) {
req.body;
queryString = req.body.querystring;

let data = JSON.stringify({
    "query": {
        "match": {
          "phonetic": {
            "query": queryString,
            "fuzziness": "AUTO",
            "operator": "and"
          }
        }
      }
});

const { body } = await client.search({
    index: 'phoneticindex',
    body: data
});

res.send(body.hits.hits) 
});
```

What is wrong with my API and/or the way I am trying to communicate with it?

UPDATE: I receive the following error in the fetch catch block: 'TypeError: Failed to fetch'

When I create a request in Postman I receive the expected response.

UPDATE 2: This is most probably an SSL related issue. The webapp is expecting an API with a valid certificate. Obviously my API can only have a self signed cert which is not enough here. How can I generate a valid cert for an API which is running on the local network and not publicly available?

UPDATE 3: I managed to make it work by changing the fetch parameters like this:

```
 fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    mode: 'cors',
    body: raw,
    agent: httpsAgent,
    redirect: 'follow',
  })
```

and on the API side I added the following headers:

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : 'https://localhost:2200',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' : 'POST',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' : 'Content-Type, Authorization'
```

I also added app.use(cors()) and regenerated the self-signed certificates.

Comment: Where are the application and API hosted?

Comment: Did you try to debug all values in request handler? E.g., what is `req.body` equal to? What does `await client.search(...)` resolves to?

Comment: Both the webapp and the API is hosted on localhost.

Comment: When I create a request in Postman I receive the expected response.

Comment: Do you replicate the postman request with the same url or do you use `localhost:3003`? Have you checked your firewall rules?

Comment: I have tried both localhost and IP address. Firewall is off.

Comment: You are missing the `/search` in your route code it seems. 
It should be `router.post('/search'..` . The end points are not matching and thats why fetch throwing error i guess

Comment: The route is correct. It is defined in the app.js file: 
app.use('/search', searchRouter);

Comment: Everything else looks good actually then! Restart your system maybe, check SSL options again once, mention headers/mode/cache in fetch connect options. these are the mini hacks i can think of sorry ;(

Comment: "*Obviously my API can only have a self signed cert which is not enough here.*" Can you share how you reached the conclusion that "*a self signed cert [....] is not enough here*"? Why would it matter if it was self-signed if you trust the root CA from which it was generated...?